# Knockout unwrap observable does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have made an icon custom binding that works fine if I do something like this

```
<div data-bind="icon: 'icon-name'"></div>
```

I want the icon to be variable so in my view model I have:

```
var element = {
  icon: ko.computed(function() {
    return 'icon-' + iconType();
  }
}
```

In my html I have:

```
<div data-bind="icon: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(icon)"></div>
```

But this is not working.
Note that if I insert another div before like this:

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(icon)"></div>
```

I get a div with exactly the name of the icon that I wanted, lets say 'icon-1'.

So my guess is that unwrapObservable does not give me the text in the format I need.

Any ideas how to fix this?

The icon binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.icon = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var icon = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            $(element).html(icons[icon]);
         }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `unwrapObservable` here at all?

Comment: I get the exactly same results if I use icon: icon and text: icon

Comment: I use unwrap trying to get the value of the computed element to work with my custom binding that works as I said in the first line

Comment: Right, so it sounds like knockout is working exactly as it should.  What is the `icon` binding - sounds like that's the thing that's not working

Comment: Well the first example with data-bind="icon: 'icon-name'" works, it waits for the name of the icon

Comment: A static string being passed to it is different to a possibly variable result of a function.  Can you show us the binding code?  It's within that binding that you may need to be using `unwrapObservable`.

Comment: Updated the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `init`, you need to handle [`update`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html#the-update-callback), for when the value changes, which is what's happening with the computed:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.icon = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var icon = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).html(icons[icon]);
    }
}
```

You should then be able to bind as normal, without needing to upwrap the value within the binding:

```
<div data-bind="icon: icon"></div>
```

With regards to `init`, [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html#the-init-callback) says:

> Knockout will call your init function once for each DOM element that you use the binding on. There are two main uses for init:
>
> 1. To set any initial state for the DOM element
> 2. To register any event handlers so that, for example, when the user clicks on or modifies the DOM element, you can change the state of the associated observable

IE it's not necessary here, you can do everything you need through `update`.

Comment: Oh , you're right, looking in the wrong direction, thanks!